# Logging output of user disable and group removal - Powershell no Quest

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have some existing code that I've pieced together from my google searches.

Hi All,

I spent some time googling to find the code needed and this is what I have below.
What I'm wanting to do is log the groups being removed from a user either.

a) Into a local text (.log) file
or
b) Into the users "Notes" field.

I've found code on how to do logging if I use quest addin, but cannot fathom how to make it fit WITHOUT using quest.

Doing this as a learning + work functional task to make it speedier to disable users.

```
Import-Module activedirectory -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
$username = read-host "Username"
$users= get-aduser $username

Function RemoveMemberships
{
param([string]$SAMAccountName) 
$user = Get-ADUser $SAMAccountName -properties memberof

$userGroups | %{get-adgroup $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -confirm:$false -member    $SAMAccountName}
$userGroups | %{get-adgroup $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -confirm:$false -member    $SAMAccountName}    $userGroups = $user.memberof
$userGroups = $null
}

$users | %{RemoveMemberships $_.SAMAccountName}

Move-ADObject $users -TargetPath "OU=Disabled Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" -PassThru | Disable-ADAccount
```

edit: The inclusion of the Exchange PSSnapin is for enhancing with disabling on GAL. I have code, but didn't include it in this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple on-screen answer using Write-Host

```
$userGroups | %{Write-Host "Removing user from group $_"; get-adgroup $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -confirm:$false -member $SAMAccountName}
```